# Modifying webroot in Nitro

Tags: craft3, nitro

I've just changed the `webroot` for one of my Craft Nitro sites. After running `nitro apply` and it completing. I'm getting `404 - Not Found Nginx`

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a command I'm missing?

```
  hostname:  test-nitro.nitro
  php:   8.0
  webroot:   public_html
  path:  ~/Documents/test-nitro
```

I've essentially moved everything from the `web` folder which was working, into a newly created folder called `public_html`

Comment: This was fixed updating to the latest Nitro and re-applying

Comment: Want to add that as an official answer, @JMKelley?